# Geocoding java android multiple results

Tags: java, android, geocoding

I am using the geocoder class to find functional locations on google maps.
For instance:

```
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("winkel", 20);
```

winkel is dutch for shop.

If I do this, he only returns 10 addresses. This does not satisfy my needs. I do want to be able to have them all (so 20)...

I've already surfed a little bit, and maybe I should use the google maps api together with php (or something similar), but I would prefer it to use the dedicated java class for android.
Who has a suggestion?

Thank in advance.

Comment: How can you be sure that 10 are not all found locations?

Comment: go to belgium on google maps and type winkels... you will have like +100 results?

Answer (score 0):

Android recomends the maxResults should be from 1 to 5 [check this out][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29 so you may have to reconsider your requirement of fetching 20 results, this not only makes your app very slow but also eats up a lot of your phone's battery

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I already read that, but this does not helps me with my problem. With other search items I put in (eg. mac donalds). He will only return me one value (and we have more than one macdonalds in our neighbourhood). I might be happy with 5 results, but if you ask, search nearby mac donalds and he only gives you one solution it is insufficient...